# Rename AD user Name using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the below code where I am getting all the users for a specific OU whose name starts with **clean1_**.

I have to rename the property name and remove the **clean1_** only from it

```
$mydomain = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
$str=""
$str+='W'+$mydomain[1]
$ds = $mydomain.Split('.')
$dcs1=$ds[0].Substring(1)+"92-CAP"

$path = "OU=Accounts,OU=IT,OU=$dcs1,DC=z,DC=if,DC=at,DC=net" 


$ExportPath=@()
$Result=@()
$ExportPath = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $path | Select-object Name | where {$_.Name -match"clean1_*"}

foreach($Usr in $ExportPath)
{
    
    $Rename = Rename-ADObject -NewName ($_.Name -replace '^clean1_')

}
```

Please let me know how what to pass in **NewName** without **clean1_**

Comment: What name is that? The SamAccountName, or the DisplayName or ?/

Comment: @Theo: DisplayName

Comment: I can't test this out at the moment, but try `Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -like 'clean1_*'" -SearchBase $path -Properties DisplayName | Set-ADUser -DisplayName ($_.DisplayName -replace '^clean1_')`

Comment: @Theo: One question. If I change the Sam Name, will it change the display name also?

Comment: No, The displayname is nothing more than that. The SamAccountName has nothing to do with that

Comment: @Theo: I tried but Displayname showing blank. `Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -like 'clean1_*'"` when I do `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like 'clean1_*'"` it is returning values like `clean1_Panda, Anwesha (WA92-001)`

Comment: Ah, ok, so it is the Name (cn) you want to change. In that case `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like 'clean1_*'" -SearchBase $path | Rename-ADObject -NewName ($_.Name -replace '^clean1_')`

Comment: @Theo:Thanks a lot

Comment: @Theo: I just tested the script. it is executing without any error but no changes in AD

Comment: Does `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like 'clean1_*'" -SearchBase $path` find any results ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: Yes. finds result fine. provides names like `clean1_Panda, Anwesha (WA92-001)`

Comment: Try the same command as Theo mentioned but use curly braces instead: `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like 'clean1_*'" -SearchBase $path | Rename-ADObject -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^clean1_' }`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: As you can see in my code, I am executing the `Rename-ADObject` inside `foreach`, so in this can what to pass in `-identity`?

Comment: Yea in this case identity is bound from pipeline, there is no need to pass it anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245884/discussion-between-empty-coder-and-santiago-squarzon).